# REST API best practice - resource as parameter

Tags: rest, parameters, url-parameters

Just as OO frequently involves methods where the parameters are objects, it seems that REST inevitably leads to needing to pass a resource as a parameter.  How is this best done?

One way seems to be that the scalar key(s) for the resource are the parameter(s).  So we might pass `fooid=21` in order to identify a resource of type foo.  It might be that a single scalar isn't enough to identify the resource, so we might need to pass `footype=a&fooelement=2`.  This isn't looking very nice, because it isn't made clear that these scalar parameters are actually connected and refer to a single resource.

Really, if the parameter is a resource, shouldn't it be referred to by its URI?  So we might want to pass something more like `/foo/21` or `/foo/a/2`.  But then there's a question as to what to call the parameter.  Should it be `foo=/foo/21`?  Probably not.  The obvious snag is that the resource is now over specified.  We know that `/foo/21` is an instance of a foo resource without being told anything more, and we don't want it to be possible to write `bar=/foo/21`.

We don't really want a totally neutral name for the parameter, such as `resource=/foo/21` because it is uninformative and hard to use if more than one parameter is a resource.

So maybe the parameter name should be something descriptive of the interaction between the parameter and the resource/method to which it is being supplied.  But how easy is it to find a suitable description?

Has anyone had any thoughts on these issues?

Comment: 'that REST inevitably leads to needing to pass a resource as a parameter.' I can't see that. What would be the usecase for this?

Answer (score 2):

Basically, you're right that the resource should be referred by its full URI. That's the best practice. Period. You're wrong that it's over-specified, because the semantics of the URI are transparent to REST. A client or server shouldn't rely on the URI to infer the type of a resource. That's what the media type header is for.

How to name the parameter really depends on the relationship with the parent resource. For instance, if you have a car resource and a driver resource, there's nothing wrong to have `car.current_driver = 'http://myapi/drivers/12'` as long as the documentation for the Car media type is clear on what current_driver is. The Car resource shouldn't accept anything but a resource with the media type for Driver when there's an attempt to set it through any method.